# Android widget onClick isn't working

Tags: android, android-intent, onclick, widget

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I had this working last night, I messed with the code and I'm pretty sure I have it back to where it was yet it simply doesn't do anything when clicked.

Here is my code

```
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onUpdate(): ");

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.xx.xx"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );


    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image, pendingIntent);

    }        
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

I'm simply trying to take the user to the market when the widget is clicked but nothing at all happens.

Is this a simple fix?

Answer (score 7):

OH MY GOD. I've spent about 4-5 hours on this.. just realized what I've done wrong.

I was missing 'appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);' after my setOnClickPendingIntent.

The joys of programming.

Answer (score 0):

For Handling Click on Home Screen Widget you will need Register an Custom Reviver in manifast as:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="com.imranandroid.xxx.xxxx.ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK"/>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED"/>

</intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

and Attach this action with Widget Layout or with Button:

```
public class SlientwidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK= "ActionReceiverClick";
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {  
   RemoteViews rview = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layoutmain);
    Intent active = new Intent(paramContext, SlientwidgetProvider.class);
    active.setAction(Globfilds.ACTION_WIDGET_CLICK);
    ///....
```

you can see full code here for handling click on Home Screen Widgets:

[Silenttoggle](https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Silenttoggle.rar?attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: This hasn't worked I'm afraid. Thank you though. It's also drastically different to the way almost every other way I've seen posted on the internet to do this.

Comment: @jblz : it's ok. i don't go with whole code. just check how we make widget click. this is not example from internet.